# Embedded Tomcat 10 does not listen on port in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I have a Spring Boot application which uses Tomcat. With version 9.0.36 it runs fine, and with 10.0.0-M7 fails. Part of pom.xml related to Tomcat is:

```
    </properties>
            <tomcat.version>10.0.0-M7</tomcat.version>
    </properties>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

application.yml's section responsible for Tomcat:

```
server:
  port: 28088
  servlet:
    contextPath: /rest
  main:
    web-application-type: servlet
  tomcat:
    max-threads: 64
```

With Tomcat 9.0.36, everything is fine. From the log:

```
2020-07-20 16:56:10.596  INFO 8268 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-07-20 16:56:10.637  INFO 8268 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 35ms. Found 0 MongoDB repository interfaces.
2020-07-20 16:56:11.493  INFO 8268 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 28088 (http)
2020-07-20 16:56:11.505  INFO 8268 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-07-20 16:56:11.506  INFO 8268 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.36]
2020-07-20 16:56:11.689  INFO 8268 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/rest]   : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-07-20 16:56:11.689  INFO 8268 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2278 ms
2020-07-20 16:56:12.229  INFO 8268 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[...:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}
```

But as soon as I replace 9.0.36 with 10.0.0-M7, it does not start Tomcat:

```
2020-07-20 16:59:24.184  INFO 20036 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-07-20 16:59:24.242  INFO 20036 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 51ms. Found 0 MongoDB repository interfaces.
2020-07-20 16:59:25.298  INFO 20036 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[...:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}
```

Anybody successfully used embedded Tomcat 10 with Spring Boot? I have upgraded to the latest Spring Boot 2.3.1-RELEASE to no avail.

Comment: Tomcat 9.0.36 is the version shipped with Spring Boot 2.3.1. Did you specify a external jar with the embedded Tomcat 10 to start this up? (is there even a embedded version made yet?) I think you are better off deploying war on your own Tomcat server instance.

Answer (score 2):

OK, got an answer from Spring Boot team. In short, Spring Boot is not yet compatible with Tomcat 10.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22414

Comment: It is not just Spring Boot that isn't compatible the whole Spring eco-system isn't compatible as Tomcat10 is using the new JakartaEE namespaces whereas everything until now has been build using the JavaEE namespaces. So without everything changing over (or supporting both) it won't be supported in the near future (although something might be scheduled for Spring 6 I believe).